# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/common_signin_btn_light_text_pressed')

Tags: android, android-studio, android-color

I have built my app earlier using the Android studio 1.1. I had no problems then. After upgrading I am getting the following error when I try to rebuild my app.

```
D:\-----\src\main\res\color\common_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
Error:(4, 55) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_pressed').
Error:(5, 85) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_disabled').
Error:(6, 55) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_focused').
Error:(7, 56) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_disabled').
Error:(8, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/common_signin_btn_dark_text_default').
D:\-------\src\main\res\color\common_signin_btn_text_light.xml
Error:(4, 55) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/common_signin_btn_light_text_pressed').
Error:(5, 85) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/common_signin_btn_light_text_disabled').
Error:(6, 55) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/common_signin_btn_light_text_focused').
Error:(7, 56) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/common_signin_btn_light_text_disabled').
Error:(8, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/common_signin_btn_light_text_default').
Error:Execution failed for task ':colorBookPro:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I tried to search for solutions but couldn't find any solution. This is my build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'    

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demo"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':main')
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-2.4.7.jar')
}
```

The files are in the res/color folder like this.
[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmacP.jpg)
I also tried using API 23 and build tools 23.0.1 and many other options. I don't seem to understand the problem as it didn't exist the first time.
I built the app 2 months back. I am new to coding so please bear with me if I have written anything silly. I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are those color files ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your suggestions but unfortunately none of them worked. I finally solved the error by replacing the color sources in common_signin_button_text_light.xml with

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled" />
    <item android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_default" />
```

and common_signin_button_text_dark.xml with

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused" />
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled" />
    <item android:color="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" />
```

It seems the resources files update after updating Android Studio.

I was able to successfully build my app after making above changes.

Answer (score 2):

[image: image describing where its located]

Inside the **color.xml** you can define colors as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<item name="blue" type="color">#FF33B5E5</item>
<item name="purple" type="color">#FFAA66CC</item>
<item name="green" type="color">#FF99CC00</item>
<item name="orange" type="color">#FFFFBB33</item>
<item name="red" type="color">#FFFF4444</item>
<item name="darkblue" type="color">#FF0099CC</item>
<item name="darkpurple" type="color">#FF9933CC</item>
<item name="darkgreen" type="color">#FF669900</item>
<item name="darkorange" type="color">#FFFF8800</item>
<item name="darkred" type="color">#FFCC0000</item>

<integer-array name="androidcolors">
    <item>@color/blue</item>
    <item>@color/purple</item>
    <item>@color/green</item>
    <item>@color/orange</item>
    <item>@color/red</item>
    <item>@color/darkblue</item>
    <item>@color/darkpurple</item>
    <item>@color/darkgreen</item>
    <item>@color/darkorange</item>
    <item>@color/darkred</item>
</integer-array>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happen because of you use color which is not included in your `color.xml` file.

Add color name and values in your both color files like below.

```
<color name="common_signin_btn_dark_text_pressed">SomeColorValue(Hash Code)</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In color.xml you should declare color:-

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="common_singin_btn_light_text_pressed">#0288D1</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to src\main\res\layout folder structure.

In XML, replace the string:

```
"android:textColor:@colour/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused"
```

with:

```
android:textColor="#90000000".
```

Solved the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem when I was updating **google-play-services_lib** module, I've had in my project, to the newer version of **Google Play Services**.

Here is the screenshot of the structure to the **common_colors.xml** from the old **google-play-services_lib** where the `common_signin_btn_dark_text_pressed` is located:

[image]

And here is the content of the **common_colors.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Sign-in Button Colors -->
    <color name="common_signin_btn_dark_text_default">@android:color/white</color>
    <color name="common_signin_btn_dark_text_pressed">@android:color/white</color>
    <color name="common_signin_btn_dark_text_disabled">#FFAAAAAA</color>
    <color name="common_signin_btn_dark_text_focused">@android:color/white</color>
    <color name="common_signin_btn_light_text_default">#FF737373</color>
    <color name="common_signin_btn_light_text_pressed">@android:color/white</color>
    <color name="common_signin_btn_light_text_disabled">#FFAAAAAA</color>
    <color name="common_signin_btn_light_text_focused">#FF737373</color>
    <color name="common_signin_btn_default_background">#FFDD4B39</color>
    <color name="common_action_bar_splitter">#d2d2d2</color>
</resources>
```

So, basically, include that content in your **res** -> **values** -> **colors.xml**, and everything should work fine again!