# Build error for Android with Kony Studio 5.6.2

Tags: android, build, temenos-quantum

I am having a problem while building Android project with Kony Studio 5.6.2. The following is the error info:

```
[exec-shell] 
[exec-shell] -code-gen:
[exec-shell] [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[exec-shell] [mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
[exec-shell]      [echo] Handling aidl files...
[exec-shell]      [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
[exec-shell]      [echo] ----------
[exec-shell]      [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[exec-shell]      [echo] ----------
[exec-shell]      [echo] Handling Resources...
[exec-shell]      [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
[exec-shell]      [aapt] /Users/mobile/mbanking-client/temp/MobileApp/build/luaandroid/dist/MobileBanking/res/drawable/line_divider.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'color' with value '@color/divider_grey').
[exec-shell]      [aapt] 
[exec-shell] 
[exec-shell] BUILD FAILED
[exec-shell] /Users/mobile/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[exec-shell] /Users/mobile/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:694: null returned: 1
[exec-shell] 
[exec-shell] Total time: 5 seconds
[11-03-2016 10:34:03]Ant build error=exec-shell returned: 1
[11-03-2016 10:34:03]Build Generation failed for platform Android.
[11-03-2016 10:34:03]Total time taken: 190146 ms
[11-03-2016 10:34:03]Total time taken: 190343 ms
[11-03-2016 10:34:03]Build Generation is successful for all the selected platforms
[11-03-2016 10:34:03]<-----------Build Generation job is completed--------------->
```

I am wondering that if anyone could help?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Refresh workspace. Refresh project. Exit Kony. Delete the temp folder where the builds are created. Restart Kony. Clean & Build. That should usually fix such issues in kony. However, here's a question dealing with the same issue, but on Android : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34628092/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-color-with-value-color-com

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by my workmate.

Download and install mono then it works.